# VBA/SQL giving 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I am having issues with my query. Pardon me as I am new to VBA. I have the query as part of VBA code and it probably has to do with aliases or syntax perhaps. I have tried several things but still no luck

```
"SELECT mtn.* " &_
"FROM ( " &_
"SELECT [PATIENT_KEY], [RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY] " &_
"FROM [claim_detail$] " &_
"WHERE  [CPT_HCPS_PROC_CD] IN ('82330', '82374', '82435', '82565', '82947', '84132', '84295', '84520') " &_
"GROUP BY [PATIENT_KEY], [RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY] HAVING COUNT([CPT_HCPS_PROC_CD]) >= 8) AS [pat_matches] " &_
"INNER JOIN [claim_detail$] AS mtn ON " &_
"mtn.[PATIENT_KEY] = [pat_matches].[PATIENT_KEY] AND " &_
"mtn.[RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY] = [pat_matches].[RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY] " &_
"WHERE mtn.[CPT_HCPS_PROC_CD] IN ('82330', '82374', '82435', '82565', '82947', '84132', '842
```

I keep getting: Microsoft Access Database Engine (91, 2) : No value given for one or more required parameters.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: (1) Explain what the issues are with your query.  (2) Print out the query string *as the query string* rather than a bunch of string concatenations that make it hard to follow.  (3) How you are calling the database is possibly also relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

This typically indicates that one or more field names are misspelled.